# How to sort sql server result based on first smallest to largest, Numeric followed by Alpha

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LTRIM(BINNUMBER)='999999' THEN 'NO BIN' ELSE BINNUMBER END AS BINNUMBER,
                                      --SELECT BINNUMBER,
                                      SUBCLASS,
                                      STYLE_DESCRIPTION,
                                      style_code,
                                      color_code,
                                      size_code,
                                      QUANTITY_SOLD,
                                      SOH,
                                      CURRENT_PRICE     
                                      FROM #Final_By_Selection_withMinBin
                                      --WHERE BINNUMBER NOT BETWEEN '1' AND '999999'  || NOT BETWEEN @intFrom_BinNo AND @intTo_BinNo
                                      WHERE MIN_BINNUMBER NOT BETWEEN @intFrom_BinNo AND @intTo_BinNo
                                      ORDER BY

                                     --LEFT(size_master_id,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',size_master_id)-1), -- alphabetical sort
                                     --CONVERT(VARCHAR,SUBSTRING(size_master_id,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',size_master_id),LEN(size_master_id))) -- numerical sort

                                        substring(size_master_id, 0,patindex('%[0-9]%',size_master_id))+right ('00000' + substring(size_master_id,
                                        patindex('%[0-9]%',size_master_id) , len(size_master_id)),5)
                                                                END
```

Comment: I can't read your code, therefore I can't help you.

Comment: can you provide some examples like expected result..??

Comment: I have a result set of numeric value as well as alpha. I have to sort the first numeric in ascending and then the alpha value .

Comment: Format your code properly.  No one is going to read that.  Also read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm not even sure what column we are looking at.  Maybe try posting a formatted, simplified example of your problem.  Try to include expected results and things you have tried already.  Sample data would help people understand at a glance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column to be in the format of 'NNNNAAA' (N-numeric, A-alphabets), you can use

```
ORDER BY 
CAST(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%', description) > 0 THEN 0 ELSE -1 END AS INT),

CAST(CASE WHEN substring(description,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', description),ISNULL( NULLIF( PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%', description) - 1, -1 ),LEN(description) )) = '' THEN 2147483647
          ELSE substring(description,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', description),ISNULL( NULLIF( PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%', description) - 1, -1 ),LEN(description) )) 
          END AS INT),

substring(description,PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%', description),LEN(description) - PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%', description) + 1
```

To explain:

PATINDEX gets me the first alpha's index / first numeric's index in that string. So, first I am sorting the output by whether a numeric part is present or not and then sorting the same by alpha part. Hope this helps you.

Comment: It gives an error - Argument data type int is invalid for argument 2 of patindex function.

Comment: its dispalying both numeric and alpha value . eg - 77E , 776, TRRTR

Comment: Actually, the data is a style code which is a combination of alpha and numeric, only alpha and also only numeric value. I want to sort the data first on the basis of numeric value then alpha value.

Comment: There is only one column for style code . Not two column.

Comment: No, it didn't work . First only numeric value will sort on ascending order then the alphanumeric value is sorted.

Comment: if aaa,77,88,77a,788 are the data values, then what should be your sort order? should it be 77,77a,88,788,aaa?? or 77,88,788,77a,aaa??

Comment: Great :). I have updated my answer already. Can you please mark it as answer if it worked?

Comment: I am new to StackOverflow, from where i can mark it as answer. -  sabhari karthik